# Performance of Camel SQL script is worse than script using JPA to migrate a database

Tags: apache-camel

We have a Camel integration route with two different solutions, one using SQL and the other one using JPA.

Original script using SQL:

```
@Component
public class PersonRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonRoute(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        final JsonDataFormat json = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
        json.setUnmarshalType(PersonEntity.class);

    from("sql:SELECT * FROM `my_table`?repeatCount=1%26dataSource=#importDataSource")
        .autoStartup("{{startupMyRoute}}")
        .threads(10)
        .to("sql:"
          + "INSERT INTO my_table (`id`, `name`, `age`) "
          + "values(:#${body[ID]},:#${body[NAME]},:#${body[AGE]})"
          + "?dataSource=#jpaDataSource");
    }
}
```

Solution using JPA:

```
@Component
public class PersonRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public PersonRoute(PersonRepository personRepository) {
      this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void configure() {
        JsonDataFormat json = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
        json.setUnmarshalType(PersonEntity.class);

        from("sql:SELECT" +
             "  JSON_MERGE(" +
             "    '{}'," +
             "    JSON_OBJECT(" +
             "      'id', `person`.`id`," +
             "      'name', `person`.`name`," +
             "      'age', `person`.`age`" +
             "        )" +
             "  )" +
             "FROM `person`?repeatCount=1%26dataSource=#importDataSource")
        .routeId("PersonRoute")
        .autoStartup("{{startupPersonRoute}}")
        .threads(10)
        .process(
            xchg -> {
                Map<String, Object> resultMap = (Map) xchg.getIn().getBody();
                xchg.getIn()
                .setBody(resultMap.entrySet().stream().findFirst().map(Entry::getValue).orElse(null),String.class);
            })
        .unmarshal(json)
        // Aggregate until we have 1200 records OR 15 seconds have elapsed:
        .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
        .completionSize(1200)
        .completionInterval(15000)
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(
            xchg ->
                personRepository.saveAll(
                    (List<PersonEntity>) xchg.getIn().getBody()))
        .end();
    }
}
```

When migrating 500k rows we have the following results

- SQL solution 2m16s
- JPA solution 1m36s

I understand it doesn't look like a big difference, but for real entities with many foreign keys and constraints, this difference goes from 3 to 6 hours.

I see no reason for JPA to perform better than SQL, so I believe I am missing some configuration that allows me to run this much faster.

Is JPA supposed to be faster than SQL? If so, why? And if not, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for the difference in performance is because the JPA approach is aggregating the records and saving the records in a batch (with 1200 records OR after waiting 15 seconds) as one transaction.

Here is a good post about how saveAll() is faster than saving individual records - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall

If in the JPA code there was no aggregation and you saved the records one at a time, the performance may be same.